# Manipulating strings in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I have a NSString with 10 characters. I need to add a dash - at character position 4 and 8. What is the most efficient way to do this? thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a mutable string, not a NSString.

```
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:old_string];
[str insertString:@"-" atIndex:8];
[str insertString:@"-" atIndex:4];
```

Fixed code based on [stko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/531228/stko)'s answer, which is bug free.

Answer (score 6):

You should take care to insert the dash at the highest index first. If you insert at index 4 first, you will need to insert at index 9 instead of 8 for the second dash.

e.g. This does not produce the desired string...

```
NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"abcdefghij"];

[s insertString:@"-" atIndex:4];  // s is now @"abcd-efghij"
[s insertString:@"-" atIndex:8];  // s is now @"abcd-efg-hij"
```

While this one does:

```
NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"abcdefghij"];

[s insertString:@"-" atIndex:8];  // s is now @"abcdefgh-ij"
[s insertString:@"-" atIndex:4];  // s is now @"abcd-efgh-ij"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different way of doing this — which is to get a mutable copy of your original NSString.

```
NSMutableString *newString = [originalString mutableCopy];

[newString insertString:@"-" atIndex:8];
[newString insertString:@"-" atIndex:4];
```

Since you're on the iPhone - it's important to note that since the `newString` is created with `mutableCopy` you own the memory and are responsible for releasing it at some future point.